# sql Sum time that occurs in an interval

Tags: sql, datetime

i have a lot of data that has at start time and a finnish time. These are formated i datetime format.

i want to sum the time that occurs in an timeinterval

if  specify the time interval 08-11
i only want to get the time between these to even if the evvent progresses from 06 to 12

Comment: which dbms are you using: oracle, mysql,sqlserver?

Comment: Can you just select these intervals (without group by and sum)?

Comment: can you give sample date data @hultegard

Comment: Also, please post sample data and wanted result!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you could do it like that:

```
SELECT  SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR,StartTimeColumn,EndTimeColumn)) AS ElapsedHoursTotal,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartTimeColumn,EndTimeColumn)) AS ElapsedMinutesTotal,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTimeColumn,EndTimeColumn)) AS ElapsedSecondsTotal,
FROM    dbo.YourTable
```

You will have to find the perfekt interval (First Parameter of DATEDIFF Function) for your requirements... Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Nanoseconds,...

Answer (score 0):

Im using mssql 2012

the problem is that i can get the full elapsed time from start to finnish but I only want the part that matches my search
if the pattern i match for is 8-11
thing one 08-12 should produce 3 hours
thing two 10-11 should produce 1 hour
thing tre 9.30- 14 shoud produce 1.5 hour